# Prove that triangle $EDC$ is similar to triangle $EAB$, given $CD$ is parallel to $AB$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, similitude

Prove that triangle $EDC$ is similar to triangle $EAB$, given $CD$ is parallel to $AB$, and specify a reason for similarity.

[image]

I deduce that triangles $ACE$ and $CDE$ have common height, triangle $EAB$ and triangle $EDB$ have a common height, $ED/EA$ is known.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BornPerson Please see the right side diagram in [Two lines in a plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry)#Two_lines_in_a_plane).

Comment: You are in the AAA case of similitude...

Comment: Similarity can be concluded immediately via the intercept/side-splitter theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [alternate angle theorem](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/alternate-interior-angles/) to lines $AB, CD$ and $AE$. Thus, $\angle CDE \cong \angle BAD$. Similarly, $\angle DCE \cong \angle ABE$. This is enough to declare similarity based on that three angles in one triangle are congruent to three angles in another triangle. You can also use that vertical angles are congruent.